# Java: Forcing Not to Override

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have a super class with a final method

`public final void foo(){ ... }`

Comment: you can add the method with the same name, but different signature. Or else the compiler will bother you.

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem in your design. Unless child `foo` has different signature or the super `foo()` is not final, I don't see it happening.

Comment: I need to have the two methods exactly the same, I wonder if there is some annotation for this purpose.

Comment: This sounds like you got the wrong idea about some other concept, and you're trying to get it to work in entirely the wrong way. What you are trying to do is not a good idea.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. 'Override' *means* providing another method with the same name and signature. You can't do that 'without overriding'. Period.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do it.

Overriding a method in subclass with its superclass method marked `final` is not possible
. You can add a method with different signature

The purpose of `final` keyword applied to a method is that it doesn't allow subclass method to override it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `final` keyword is there to prevent this.
See [final methods in Java on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the `final` super method.but you can overload it.

> Make a method final only if it has an implementation that should not be changed and it is critical to the consistent state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of final is to prevent from overriding.So, you can not override final methods.
Still you can overload final methods.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear why you *have to* have the same name. Either it’s intended to be a different method, then it can have a different name without problems or you are trying to do some sort of overriding you claimed not to do.

If your subclass needs an interface implementation which interferes with that method consider an inner class for that interface implementation.

Otherwise a method in the subclass does not override a superclass method with the same name if either:

- it has different parameter types
- the superclass method is private
- the superclass method is package-private and the subclass resides in a different package